# Sum and Divisibility Puzzle

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have $5$ positive integers: $a,b,c,d,e$.

$a,b,c,d,e$ are all different, and $a\mid b\mid c\mid d\mid e$, in other words the ratios
$$\frac ba, \frac cb,   \frac dc,  \frac ed $$ are all integers.

$$a+b+c+d+e = 47.$$

I need to find out what $a,b,c,d,e$ are. Apparently there is only one solution to this.

I did some trial and error and came to an answer of $1,2,4,8,32$. But I really have no idea how to come to this conclusion more formally.

The problem comes from a section of my book that talks about prime factorization.

I can figure that the direction that I need to go in is looking at the fact that 47 is prime and that adding the prime factorizations of a,b,c,d,e will give me 47 in some elegant way.

Can someone provide some direction?

Comment: The title is very misleading - this has nothing to do with unique factorisation.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Since $47$ is prime and all variables must be divisible by $a$, one must have $a=1$. Now $b+c+d+e=46=2\times23$, of which $b$ must be a divisor. It is not hard to exclude $b\in\{23,46\}$ and $b=1=a$ is forbidden, so $b=2$. Now $c+d+e=44=2\times2\times11$. Again $c\geq11$ is easy to rule out and $c\leq2$ is forbidden, so $c=4$. One gets $d+e=40=2\times2\times2\times 5$. Since $d$ must be a multiple of $c=4$, we have $d\in\{8,20,40\}$, of which only $d=8$ is feasible. This leaves $e=32$.

Comment: It seems very odd to me that this answer (which solves the problem, proving that the given solution is unique, without pulling any rabbits out of hats) is not the accepted answer. (The currently-accepted answer happens to "work" in this case but will not for, e.g., a|b|c with sum=9.)

Comment: Minor point:  It's actually $e$ that must be $1$ (and backwards from there to $a=32$).

Comment: @BarryCipra: That is because somebody edited the question to say something different from what it originally did. I've changed it bas to what is used to be.

Answer (score 4):

**Simplest method:**

Convert the number into binary.

$$47_{10}=(2^5+2^3+2^2+2^1+2^0)_{10}=101111_2$$

The intermediate step gives you the answer.

$$47=32+8+4+2+1$$

This works because every binary digit has exactly twice the value of the next one, and is therefore, a multiple of every digit that follows.

If suppose the binary number gave you less/more than $5$ ones, repeat the process with every number base, till you get a number with exactly $5$ ones, any number of zeroes, but no other digits. For example, $121_{10}=11111_3$, so $121=81+27+9+3+1$.

I have tried for $47$, there is no other solution. I'm not sure whether there exist natural numbers with more than one solution, but I suppose they do.

Comment: Maybe there are other solutions.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Not for 47, atleast.

Comment: It is not said that all ratios are equal, so the "basis" trick worked by chance.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, the ratios are not all equal in this problem anyway. $\frac {32}8 \neq \frac 84$

Comment: @shoover: yep, I should have written "it is not said that the ratios are powers of a common base". The method is still invalid because it is limited to that specific circumstance.

Answer (score 2):

All numbers being different imply that all ratios are at least $2$ and the smallest possible sum is $16+8+4+2+1=31$, just $16$ units from $47$.

Obviously, $a=32$ fixes that, but let us make sure there are no other solutions by trying to increase each unknown in turn while adjusting the previous ones with right-to-left doubling (or tripling or quadrupling... as necessary, but this does not arise here):

$\color{green}{\underline{32}+8+4+2+1=47}$.

$24+\underline{12}+4+2+1=43$.

$32+\underline{16}+4+2+1>47$.

$24+12+\underline6+2+1=45$.

$32+16+\underline8+2+1>47$.

$24+12+6+\underline3+1=46$.

$32+16+8+\underline4+1>47$.

$32+16+8+4+\underline2>47$.

Comment: At the time you answered this question, somebody had modified the question to reverse the divisibility relations. This being an error, I've returned it to its original sense. But this means that this answer is now backwards with respect to what the question says. Excuse the inconvenience.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: thanks for the notice. I prefer the left-to-right-increasing order, which makes my notation more readable I guess.

Answer (score 2):

First, if $a \geq 2$, then you'd have $b \geq (2)(2) = 4$, and $c\geq (2)(4) = 8$, and $d\geq (2)(8) = 16$ and $e\geq (2)(16) = 32$, since each of the "adjacent ratios" must be at least $2$.  But then $a + b + c + d + e \geq 62$, which doesn't work.  Hence $a = 1$.

Next, if $b = 3$, then $b, c, d, e$ are all divisible by $3$, which means $a + b + c + d + e$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $3$, which doesn't work since $47$ is congruent to $2$ rather than $1$.  Also, if $b \geq 4$, then $a+b+c+d+e > 47$ as above.  Therefore we must have $b = 2$, since $b > a = 1$.

Now $c = bk = 2k$ for some $k>1$.  If $c = (2)(3) = 6$, then $a+b+c+d+e = 0$ mod $3$, which again doesn't work, while if $c \geq (2)(4) = 8$, then $a+b+c+d+e > 47$ again.  Hence $c = (2)(2) = 4$.

At this point we have $(a, b, c) = (1, 2, 4)$, so $a+b+c=7$ and therefore $d+e = 40$.  Also, $d = 4m$ and $e = dn = 4mn$ for some integers $m, n > 1$.

Thus $40 = 4m + 4mn = 4(m + mn)$, so $10 = m + mn = m(1 +n)$.  The only way to write $10$ as the product of two integers both greater than $1$ is $10 = (2)(5)$, so either $m = 2$ and $1+n = 5$, or $m=5$ and $1+n = 2$.  The latter possibility is eliminated as it would mean $n=1$, so we conclude $m=2$ and $1+n=5$, so $n=4$.  That is, $d=8$ and $e=32$.

Comment: This is (IMHO) the 'right' answer to the problem - it derives the solution without any guess-and-check and explains _why_ it's unique.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**:  This answer was composed when the stipulated integer ratios were $a/b$, etc., rather than $b/a$, etc.

Writing $a/b=A$, $b/c=B$, $c/d=C$, and $d/e=D$, we have

$$e(1+D(1+C(1+B(1+A))))=47$$

which, since $47$ is prime and $1+D(1+etc.)$ is clearly greater than $1$, implies $e=1$.  This leaves

$$D(1+C(1+B(1+A)))=46=2\cdot23$$

Since $1+C(1+B(1+A))\ge1+(1+(1+1))=4$, we conclude that $D=2$ (it cannot equal $1$ since $d\not=e$), which leads to

$$C(1+B(1+A))=22=2\cdot11$$

Again, $1+B(1+A))\ge1+(1+1)=3$, so $C=2$, leaving

$$B(1+A)=10=2\cdot5$$

and this implies $B=2$ and $A=4$.  Unwinding things, we get $e=1$, $d=2$, $c=4$, $b=8$, and $a=32$.

Comment: At the time you answered this question, somebody had modified the question to reverse the divisibility relations. This being an error, I've returned it to its original sense. But this means that this answer is now backwards with respect to what the question says. Excuse the inconvenience.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, rather than redo all my formulas, I've added an explanatory note.  You did the appropriate thing in returning the question to its original version.